# Why is this ProtectedRoute configuration giving me error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement functionality that will restrict the user to visit the component if it is not an authorized user.

*this code snippets working fine in **app.tsx**

**Here is Protected route config code**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Router, Redirect, RouteProps} from 'react-router';

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<RouteProps> = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={
        props => {
          const isTrue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')));
          if (isTrue) {
            return <React.Component {...rest} {...props} />
          } else {
            return <Redirect to={
              {
                pathname: '/unauthorized',
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }
            } />
          }
        }
      } />
    )
  }

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

and getting this error

[image]

Comment: It is not defined what `rest` actually is

Comment: you can write tsx only in a `.tsx` file

Comment: @ Agney Thank you,  you save my day, actually, I am newbie to ReactJs